# Jboss EAP 6.2 AvailableCount in connection pool decresing

Tags: sql-server, jakarta-ee, jboss6.x

1.We have a **J2EE application** using Servlets & JSPs running on Jboss EAP-6.2, and using **SQL server** database.

2.Everything was fine on UAT system where users count was 20 but when we moved the same application to production system where users count is  more than 80 , we are facing issue in Jboss regarding connection pool count. This count keeps on decreasing and after 8-10 hours, users are not able to login in the system  so we need to Flush the connection pool manually by clicking the Flush button available in Datasource section in Profile tab.

3.We have checked there are no connection leakage, as we have closed all the database connection in the Finally{ } section.

4.We have also increased the max-min pool size in STANDALONE.XML file and added some validation tags recommended by RedHat site.Please see attached file.

**Question**- Is there any way by which we can automate the Flush button functionality available on Jboss Adminstrator console so that idle connections will get destroyed automatically.

Attached - Jboss console view of connection pool.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idle-timeout-minutes is the maximum time, in minutes, before an idle (unreserved/unused) connection is closed. The actual maximum time depends upon the idleRemover scan time, which is half of the smallest idle-timeout-minutes of any pool.

The idle connection is removed by IdleRemover after :

idle-timeout-minutes + 1/2 (idle-timeout-minutes)

The idle-timeout-minutes property should be configured to a value greater than 0 but less than the timeout period specified on the database server, network firewalls, etc. to permit graceful termination by JBoss before idle connections are externally severed.

Answer (score 1):

There are below recommendations to tune-up your datasource first.

1# There is a known problem with prefill = true in your release line

```
<prefill>true</prefill>
```

Please set this to false.

2# Use below datasource connection validation mechanisms:

```
<validation>
    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker" />  
</validation>
```

3# It is not recommend the following for datasources:

```
- jta="false" : It should be true
- use-ccm="false" : It should be true
```

4# You may want to ensure your database server is configured to *not* timeout connections that are idle for less than 5 minutes (the configured timeout period for your datasource in JBoss). The JBoss timeout should be lower/less than the timeout period configured on the database server to permit JBoss to gracefully timeout connections rather than permitting them to time out externally.

5# Connections reserved by application components are not subject to timeout by JBoss. Connections obtained by DataSource.getConnection() cannot be timed out by JBoss until after they have been returned to the pool (by calling Connection.close()) and remained unused in the pool for idle-timeout-minutes. Connection status is InUse between DataSource.getConnection() and Connection.close() even if no database command is active because these connections are owned by application code.

Apply the above and check the behaviour